# Can I use an object as a variable of a method in java?

Tags: java, multiple-return-values

Total beginner in coding here, so please, be as beginner friendly as possible! For instance, I've just recently learned about classes and objects in school.
Also, excuse any wrong naming/confusion :)

I've been having a lot of instances, where I'm writing a method, but want to return more than one variable from it. I thought - "What if I made a class that contained all of the variables I'm working with and then returned just it's instance from my method?

Example:

```
public class Mathematics {
    int number1;
    int number2;
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main (String [] args);


    public static <class?> MyMethod (<class Mathematics?>)
       //in here, the method works with numbers one and two, and then returns them, like so:
      return Mathematics;
    }
}
```

Now bear in mind, this is not EXACTLY what I want to do, but essentially, I want to use a class as a "container of variables" used in a method in another class.
If this is not the way to do it, I'd like to know what is (and please, keep it as simple as possible :) ).

Thanks!

Comment: You can accept and return the class directly, just like any other type?

Comment: It's called a POJO (Plain Old Java Object), and it can be used in any way that you can use other primitives and Objects (int, double, String, etc). So yes, create a POJO that contains all of your data that you want to pass to a method/return from a method.

Comment: "_but want to return more than one variable from it_" It they're all of the same type, you could also return an `Array` (or even an `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you're on the right track! This is a common coding pattern to solve precisely this problem, how to return multiple values.

```
public static Mathematics myMethod(int param1, String param2, float param3) {
    Mathematics result = new Mathematics();

    result.number1 = param1 * 2;
    result.number2 = param2.length();

    return result;
}
```

Items of note:

1. The return type is `Mathematics`.
2. The parameters can be anything. They don't need to be related to the `Mathematics` class, although they could be.
3. First, instantiate a new object with `new Mathematics()` and give it an arbitrary name.
4. Then, assign each field a value as you see fit.
5. Finally, return that variable.

Also, I changed it from `MyMethod` to `myMethod` to match the standard Java naming convention.

---

If you then want to work with that object in another method, that method should take a `Mathematics` object as a parameter.

```
public static void otherMethod(Mathematics values) {
    System.out.println("number1 is " + values.number1);
    System.out.println("number2 is " + values.number2);
}
```

Why does this method take it as a parameter while the first one returns it? The difference is whether a method wants to *receive* a set of values, or *return* one. If it wants to receive values, it needs a parameter of type `Mathematics`. If it wants to return values to the caller, it should have a return type of `Mathematics`.

In other words, are the values input, or output?

These aren't mutually exclusive, by the way. A method could both take and return an object. An example:

```
/**
 * Returns half of the input values. Does not modify the input object.
 * Instead, a new object is returned.
 */
public static Mathematics halfOf(Mathematics input) {
    Mathematics output = new Mathematics();

    output.number1 = input.number1 / 2;
    output.number2 = input.number2 / 2;

    return output;
}
```

This could then be called like so:

```
Mathematics values  = myMethod(42, "foobar", 3.14);
Mathematics altered = halfOf(values);

System.out.println("Half of " + values.param1 + " is " + altered.param1);
System.out.println("Half of " + values.param2 + " is " + altered.param2);
```

Comment: **thank you!** Knew it shouldn't be impossible :).

What if I would need to work with said "result" instance of type "Mathemathics" again in another method? would the next method have to be defined as

public static Mathemathics anotherMethod (int result.param1, String result.param2) etc?